# i have an error when creating an event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, event-handling

i have the following:

a game class

```
class Game
{
    public event EventHandler GameOver;

    public void go()
    {
        PlayerAliveEventArgs playerAlive = new PlayerAliveEventArgs(Alive);
        GameOver(this, playerAlive);
    }
}
```

then i have a class

```
public  class PlayerAliveEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public bool Alive { get; set; }

    public PlayerAliveEventArgs(bool deadOrAlive)
    {
        Alive = deadOrAlive;
    }
}
```

in another class i tie a method to the event...

```
public void Form_Load()
{
     game.GameOver += Form1_GameOverMethod; // it shows the error here.
     it says no overload of this method matches System.Eventhandler
}

public void Form1_GameOverMethod(object sender, PlayerAliveEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.Alive)
    {
        GameTimer.Enabled = false;
        gameOver = true;
        Refresh();
    }
}
```

The error is:

> Method doesn't exist in this context.

Why is that?

okay i made the following changes:

```
 public void Form1_GameOverMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      PlayerAliveEventArgs d = (PlayerAliveEventArgs)e;
      if (!d.Alive)
      {
      }
 }
```

is it okay now? or will it fire some problems when i run it (i want to save myself debugging latter on..)

Comment: The operator (+=) here adds an event handler method to your object event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GameOverMethod` doesn't exist in that context indeed. what exists however (and that's what you intended I suppose) is `Form1_GameOverMethod`.

A couple more remarks. First, before firing an event, you should check whether someone has subscribed to it or not.

```
if(GameOver!=null)
    GameOver(this, new PlayerAliveEventArgs(Alive));
```

Second, I believe you should change you event declaration to be:

```
public event EventHandler<PlayerAliveEventArgs> GameOver;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: awesome, i didnt know that.. but i dont need to regard to your first event, cause the subscription happens as soon as the form loads itself.  the game.GameOver+=Form1_GameOverMethod is inside the Form1_Load eventhandler

Comment: that might be true in this particular case, but you should take these precautions to avoid weird exceptions in other scenarios.

Answer (score 4):

Event declaration:

```
public event EventHandler<PlayerAliveEventArgs> GameOver;
```

Subscription:

```
game.GameOver += Form1_GameOverMethod;
```

Event handler:

```
private void Form1_GameOverMethod(object sender, PlayerAliveEventArgs e)
{
    bool alive = e.Alive;
}
```

Firing:

```
if (this.GameOver != null) // does any subscriber exist?
{
    this.GameOver(this, new new PlayerAliveEventArgs(..));
}
```

Comment: but when i add it . it tells me no overload to the method matches System.EventHandler ..why is that?

Comment: You must change the delegate of your event to match the Form1_GameOverMethod .. I believe you need to read about creating events...

Comment: okay.. i fixed it now.  i used casting, cause i still want to use the PlayerAliveEventArgs.. i casted it in the code from EventArgs..

Comment: @Dmitry: You need to change the signature of `event`. not of `event handler`!

Comment: @Akram: You can use `@` to specify whom do you tell :)

Comment: but with casting it works. what would be the alternative solution, if i didnt use casting?

Comment: @Dmitry: You can. But it makes no sense. In this case you hide the actual type of `e`, what for? Use the real type, why not?

Comment: okay, i got it.. i will stick to the solution i created..if it works, it works

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
game.GameOver += Form1_GameOverMethod;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you method is named `Form1_GameOverMethod`.